# vim execute command depending on file type

Tags: vim

How can I get vim to execute a command depending on the file type?

Recently I have been editing a lot of Python files and comments autoindent to the 0th column.

One way to fix this is to run the command `inoremap # X#<left><backspace><right>`

How can I get this command to run every time I open a python (*.py) file for editing?

Comment: Did you try `autocommand`?

Comment: @dlmeetei what is that/how does it work?

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

Use vim's filetype plugin mechanism.

## File-type specific code

There are (at least) two solutions to this, with one preferable to the other.

### `autocmd FileType`

This has already been posted as an answer, but the general form is

```
augroup your_group
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType python your good code
augroup END
```

This works, and has the advantage of grouping code in your vimrc.

But there is a second, more powerful, probably more performant alternative. It
is [my preferred
solution](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/tree/master/links/vim/after/ftplugin).

### `after/ftplugin`

I've [written](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604)
[extensively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15329/10604) about using filetype
plugins in vim.

The gist of it is that you need filetype detection and plugins (`filetype plugin
on` at a minimum, though you may want `filetype plugin indent on`). Then you
drop filetype specific code in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` (or a few
variants, see `:h add-filetype-plugin`, `:h ftplugin-name`, `:h ftplugin`).

So ultimately,

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
inoremap # X#<left><backspace><right>
```

---

## A few notes

It is a good practice to set `b:undo_ftplugin` properly: it helps (trust me).
You can borrow my [undo script on
Github](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/4709fec6ff745e3dc216e7eebc2149f24a21746a/links/vim/autoload/ftplugin.vim#L10).

Consider using `<buffer>`, `-buffer`, `setlocal`, and `<LocalLeader>` where
possible. This is for local stuff, after all.

### On power

A script gives you more flexibility than a single line of autocommands. You have
to jump through more hoops to do anything complex in autocommands, where in a
script they can just sit. Besides, you feel more like you're writing a program
(which you are) than a one off config.

The modularity is also perfect for organization: all your python customization
code is in one place.

And it's a lot less typing :)

### On performance

> I have *not* measured anything. Don't shoot me.

Having lots of autocommands can slow down vim, because they have to be checked
when their events fire. Rather than clog up the autocommands with filetype
stuff, use a file that is already going to be sourced for you (an ftplugin).

By piggybacking on an existing customization mechanic, you get all the benefit
and none of the risk. Again, it is almost certainly more efficient to let vim
source a file on demand for you then to try to reimplement it's ftplugin wheel.

Comment: what does `autocmd !` do? I'm also not familar with groups - what do they do / how do they work?

Comment: Try reading `:help augroup`; the internal help is my first stop for vim concepts

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your issue?

```
au FileType python inoremap # X#<left><backspace><right>
```

This autocommand runs your mapping for filetype python